# How to play Hi10p Videos in Totem?

Tags: codecs, totem, h264

I would like to know, how I can play Hi10p videos(h264 videos with 10bit colordepth) in Totem.
I know that it's possible to play those files in 13.04, but I'd rather stick to the LTS Version.

[image]

```
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:
  Installiert: 0.10.13-1
  Kandidat:    0.10.13-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.10.13-1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

libavcodec-dev:
  Installiert: (keine)
  Kandidat:    4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
         4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
         4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages 
libavcodec53:
  Installiert: 4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1  
  Kandidat:    4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
  ***    4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages 
libavcodec-extra-52:
   Installiert: (keine)
   Kandidat:    (keine)
   Versionstabelle:
libavcodec-extra-53:
   Installiert: (keine)
   Kandidat:    4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1
   Versionstabelle:
         4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
            500 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
         4:0.8.1ubuntu1 0
            500 http:// at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work in 12.04, otherwise I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: I always get this error: [link](http://abload.de/img/errorc2a3a.png) normal h264 files play.

Comment: Add it up there. I inserted whitespaces after the "http://" otherwise I could'nt post it.

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking the proper codecs. You must install `libavcodec-extra-53`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` and `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` so you can get most advanced (and don't know who assumed less used) codecs available. Those allow you to reproduce almost any kind of video. If you aren't sure, normally `ubuntu-restricted-extras` should include them all.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, I installed "libavcodec-extra-53" and "ubuntu-restricted-extras".

Comment: I added 2 packages, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` includes `video/x-h264` codec, and the high-10 profile, `-bad` should be installed to prevent incomplete set of codecs.

Comment: They were already installed.